# Fetch data from API and redirect not working - NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js

I'm trying to fetch some data from an API and based on this response redirect to a page.

App flow is:

User Click a button --> Button call a function --> Function fetch data from API and redirect to a new URL based on the fetched data.

components/Start.js

```
import { setCookie } from "nookies";

export default function Start() {
  return (
    <button className="text-2xl font-bold" onClick={CreateAPI}>
      Start &rarr;
    </button>
  );
}

async function CreateAPI() {

  const res = await fetch(`https://**********/create`);
  const data = await res.json();
  if (!data) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/maintenance",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  console.log(data);

  setCookie(null, "owner", "true", {
    maxAge: 3600,
    path: "/",
  });
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: `/${data}`,
      permanent: false,
    },
  };
}
```

index.js

```
 import Head from 'next/head'
import Start from '../components/Start'


export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen py-2">
      <Head>
        <title>xxx</title>
      </Head>

      <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full flex-1 px-20 text-center">
        <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold">
          Welcome
        </h1>


        <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-around max-w-4xl mt-6 sm:w-full">
          <a
            className="p-6 mt-6 text-center border w-96 rounded-xl hover:text-blue-600 focus:text-blue-600"
          >
            <Start />

          </a>
        </div>
      </main>
```

When I click the button I can see the data on the console, however the redirect is not happening.

If you can point on the right direction would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: That's client-side code, you should use [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) to navigate to a different page, e.g. ``router.push(`/${data}`)``.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CreateAPI` function is just returning an object that looks like this:

```
{
  redirect: {
    ...
  }
}
```

It's not actually performing a redirect anywhere. Depending on what type of router you're using, you would call the appropriate method. If you're using something like `react-router` you can use the `useNavigate` hook (docs: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

Comment: Next.js has a [built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), that's what OP is using.